# what is the proper capitalization of "hors d'oeuvre"?

Tags: capitalization

Possible options  include capitalizing either the "h", "d", and/or "o". Are any of these options considered either correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of a sentence:
Hors d'oeuvre

As a title:
Hors d'Oeuvre

As a title (French style):
Hors d'oeuvre

NEVER capitalize the "d".

Comment: French style would be _Hors d’œuvre_.

Comment: that is true, but most people do not know how to properly use or even type the special character, so the version I listed is the generally accepted one that won't be quite as confusing to Americans (since hors d'oeuvre is confusing enough for so many)